# Finding radius of convergence of Taylor Series of $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$about $x = \frac 12$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

Let the Taylor Series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ about $x=\frac 12$ be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-\frac{1}{2})^n$, where $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(\frac{1}{2})}{n!}$.
Then to find the radius of convergence of this series,
I tried to use roc= $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. But that wasn't successful.

Comment: It’s easier if you know about how complex roots of the denominator affect the radius of the power series…

Comment: Hint to check your computations: The radius of convergence is the distance from 1/2 to the closest singularity, which is $(1\pm\sqrt{-3})/2$.

Comment: You may use a decomposition of $f$ into simple fractions. It provides an explicit formula for the $a_n$.

Comment: And the fraction decomposition method @ChristopheLeuridan mentions can also explain why the distance to roots of the denominator, mentioned in other comments, is important.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh,I forgot that, thanks!

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I really didn't get that hope you can clarify a bit more about that method.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of the polynomial $X^3+1$ are $-1$, $-\zeta$, $-\zeta^2$ where $\zeta  = \exp(i2\pi/3) = (-1+i\sqrt{3})/2$. Using that $X^3+1 = (X+1)(X+\zeta)(X+\zeta)^2$ and classical methods to decompose fractions into simple elements, you get
$$\frac{1}{X^3+1} = \frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{1}{X+1}+\frac{1}{X+\zeta}+\frac{1}{X+\zeta^2}\Big).$$
Since you want Taylor expansion of $f$ at $1/2$, you evaluate this fraction at $1/2+h$ for $h$ different of $-3/2,-\zeta-1/2,-\zeta^2-1/2$.
$$f(1/2+h) = \frac{1}{(1/2+h)^3+1} = \frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{1}{3/2+h}+\frac{1}{1/2+\zeta+h}+\frac{1}{1/2+\zeta^2+h}\Big).$$
Then you use that given every non-zero complex number $c$, we have
$$\forall h \in D(0,|c|), \quad \frac{1}{c+h} = \frac{c^{-1}}{1+c^{-1}h} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c^{-1}(-c^{-1}h)^n \text{ since } |-c^{-1}h|<1.$$
Applying this formula to $3/2$, $1/2+\zeta$ and $1/2+\zeta^2$,
you derive Taylor expansion, which converges at least for $|h| < \min(3/2,|1/2+\zeta|,|1/2+\zeta^2|) = \sqrt{3}/2$. Thus, the radius of convergence $R$ is at least $\sqrt{3}/2$.

Actually, it cannot be larger since $f$ is continuous on the open disk $D(1/2,R)$, so this disk does not contain the points $-1,-\zeta,-\zeta^2$.